# Update Number of months between date in Oracle 11g

Tags: sql, oracle

We have a table `test1`, we need to update the `VALUE` column by calculating the  months between two dates. E.g. we have

```
P_DATE BETWEEN :D1 AND :D2

:D1 = 01-APR-2022
:D2 = 30-DEC-2022
```

So calculate the difference between `:D1` and `:D2` and return the number of months in the `VALUE` column. Can somebody please help to make the `UPDATE` Statement?

```
CREATE TABLE "TEST1" 
(   "TITLE" VARCHAR2(199 BYTE), 
    "AMOUNT" NUMBER, 
    "VALUE" NUMBER, 
    "P_DATE" DATE, 
    "RATE" NUMBER, 
    "FINANCIAL_YEAR" VARCHAR2(500 BYTE)
) 

REM INSERTING into TEST1
Insert into TEST1 (TITLE,AMOUNT,VALUE,P_DATE,RATE,FINANCIAL_YEAR) values ('CHAIR',28000,null,to_timestamp('07-APR-22','DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM'),33,'2021-22');
Insert into TEST1 (TITLE,AMOUNT,VALUE,P_DATE,RATE,FINANCIAL_YEAR) values ('LAPTOP',40000,null,to_timestamp('07-JUN-22','DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM'),33,'2021-22');
Insert into TEST1 (TITLE,AMOUNT,VALUE,P_DATE,RATE,FINANCIAL_YEAR) values ('BUS',2000000,null,to_timestamp('01-SEP-22','DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM'),33,'2021-22');
Insert into TEST1 (TITLE,AMOUNT,VALUE,P_DATE,RATE,FINANCIAL_YEAR) values ('WEAVING MACHINE',10000000,null,to_timestamp('01-JAN-22','DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM'),33,'2021-22');
Insert into TEST1 (TITLE,AMOUNT,VALUE,P_DATE,RATE,FINANCIAL_YEAR) values ('TABLE',50000,null,to_timestamp('01-MAY-22','DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM'),33,'2021-22');
COMMIT;
```

| TITLE | AMOUNT | VALUE | P_DATE | RATE | FINANCIAL_YEAR |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CHAIR | 28000 | 9 | 07-APR-22 | 33 | 2021-22 |
| LAPTOP | 40000 | 7 | 07-JUN-22 | 33 | 2021-22 |
| BUS | 2000000 | 4 | 01-SEP-22 | 33 | 2021-22 |
| WEAVING MACHINE | 100000000 | 12 | 1-JAN-22 | 33 | 2021-22 |
| TABLE | 50000 | 8 | 01-MAY-22 | 33 | 2021-22 |

Comment: Are you looking for [`MONTHS_BETWEEN`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/MONTHS_BETWEEN.html)?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `MONTHS_BETWEEN` function and then `ROUND` to the nearest whole month (or if you want to always round up then use `CEIL` instead of `ROUND`):

```sql
UPDATE test1
SET value = ROUND(MONTHS_BETWEEN(DATE '2022-12-30', p_date));
```

Which, for your sample data, then after the update the table contains:

| TITLE | AMOUNT | VALUE | P_DATE | RATE | FINANCIAL_YEAR |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CHAIR | 28000 | 9 | 2022-04-07 00:00:00 | 33 | 2021-22 |
| LAPTOP | 40000 | 7 | 2022-06-07 00:00:00 | 33 | 2021-22 |
| BUS | 2000000 | 4 | 2022-09-01 00:00:00 | 33 | 2021-22 |
| WEAVING MACHINE | 10000000 | 12 | 2022-01-01 00:00:00 | 33 | 2021-22 |
| TABLE | 50000 | 8 | 2022-05-01 00:00:00 | 33 | 2021-22 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/b4cd4vJn)

---

#### Update

If you only want to update the values when `P_DATE` is within a certain range then use:

```sql
UPDATE test1
SET   value = ROUND(MONTHS_BETWEEN(DATE '2022-12-30', p_date))
WHERE p_date BETWEEN DATE '2022-04-01' AND DATE '2022-12-30';
```

or, if you are using bind variables then:

```sql
UPDATE test1
SET   value = ROUND(MONTHS_BETWEEN(:D2, p_date))
WHERE p_date BETWEEN :D1 AND :D2;
```

Which, for the sample data, after the update the table contains:

| TITLE | AMOUNT | VALUE | P_DATE | RATE | FINANCIAL_YEAR |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CHAIR | 28000 | 9 | 2022-04-07 00:00:00 | 33 | 2021-22 |
| LAPTOP | 40000 | 7 | 2022-06-07 00:00:00 | 33 | 2021-22 |
| BUS | 2000000 | 4 | 2022-09-01 00:00:00 | 33 | 2021-22 |
| WEAVING MACHINE | 10000000 | *null* | 2022-01-01 00:00:00 | 33 | 2021-22 |
| TABLE | 50000 | 8 | 2022-05-01 00:00:00 | 33 | 2021-22 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/w0Lw-FzF)

Comment: Dear Expert thanks for reply, we need to enter start and end date also, if we have a date 01-01-2022 then it should not calculate because our :D1 date is 01-apr-2022